# why we chose sse(sum of square error ) to decide the best fit line in linear regression

Tags: statistics, linear-regression, data-science

we choose SSE(sum of squared error) for deciding the best fit line instead of sum of residual or sum of absolute residual

Comment: sorry some posting issue ,  my question is why we dont choose .. sum of residual , or absolute value of sum of residual to get the minimum error

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to involve programming.  The question might be appropriate on https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about statistics / mathematics instead of directly about programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose is to allow linear algebra to directly solve for equation coefficients in regression. The other fitting targets you mention cannot be used in this way. Using derivative calculus, it was found that a fitting target of lowest sum of squared error allowed a direct, non-iterative solution to the problem of fitting experimental data to equations that are linear in their coefficients - such as standard polynomial equations.

Answer (score 0):

James is right that the ability to formulate the estimates of regression coefficients as a form of linear algebra is one large advantage of the least squares estimate (minimizing SSE), but using the least squares estimate provides a few other useful properties.

With the least squares estimate you're minimizing the variance of the errors - which is often desired.  This gives us the *best linear unbiased estimator* (*BLUE*) of the coefficients (given the Gauss–Markov assumptions are met).  (Gauss-Markov assumptions and a proof showing why this formulation gives us the best linear unbiased estimates can be found [here](http://www.econ.nyu.edu/user/njenish/gauss_markov.pdf).)

With the least squares, you also end up with a unique solution (assuming you have more observations than estimated coefficients and no perfect multicollinearity).

As for using the sum of residual, this wouldn’t work well since this would be minimized by having all negative residuals.
But the sum of absolute residual is used in some linear models where you may want the estimates to be more robust to outliers and aren’t necessarily concerned with the variance of the residuals.